# How can i add a geojson file using it's local path with openlayers?

Tags: geojson, openlayers-3

I want to load a local geojson to my map using openlayers.

Here is what I currently have:

```
var gjsonFile = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: new ol.source.Vector({
format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
}),
url: './data/geojson/plan.geojson'
})
});

map.addLayer(gjsonFile);
```

But nothing is displayed, I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2
```

Anyone have a solution?

NB. 
i tried with this url:
https://c.data.osmbuildings.org/0.2/anonymous/tile/15/17607/10743.json
and it worked, so i have a problem with local paths.

Comment: Maybe the error is in the content of your local json, and not due to the path.  What happens if you download a copy of 10743.json then copy it to your local path and use `url: './data/geojson/10743.json'` ?

Comment: Yes, i've already do it, but i get the same error mentioned above in my question.

Comment: Taking a copy of 10743.json onto my localhost and then reading it works for me so perhaps you have a MIME type configuration problem on your server.  Can you access your data directly from the browser address bar? e.g.`http://yourdomain/data/geojson/plan.geojson`

Comment: Yes i think that''s the problem, because i can't access to my data by the browser.

Comment: thank you for your answer, have u any proposition to resolve it?

Comment: If you are using Windows localhost go to computer managerment, services and applications, IIS then select MIME types from the options and add an extry for extension `.geojson` type `application/json`  Other server types I've used haven't need any special setup.

Comment: thank you ^^ i will try it, i just not find the IIS in my computer management :\

Answer (score 0):

You can use `require` to read a json file from your localhost directory and use `(new GeoJSON()).readFeatures` for reading the json object. Ref the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61948057/13594097